# How many joist bores can I fit into with a single piece of Sch40 PVC?

Tags: plumbing, joists

I'm about to start the DWV plumbing in my bathroom addition. Unfortunately, some runs will have to cross joists instead of nicely running along them.

I have 2x12" and 2x8" floor joists (different floors) on 16" centers, and will be running a combination of 2" and 3" PVC. How many joists can I reasonably expect to get a single piece of Sch 40 PVC pipe through before the angle is too great to wedge it in?

I understand that I'll have to cut the pipe into smaller pieces in order to get it through the joists, as Sch40 is rather unflexible. I'm simply trying to determine how many pieces I'll need to cut it into in order to know (roughly) how many couplings I'll need to purchase to reassemble it. i.e. will I need a coupling between every single joist because I won't be able to get a 3" pipe past 2 adjacent 2x8" joists, or will I be able squeeze it through 2 joists, but not the 3rd, or... Maybe I can get the 2" pipe through 3 12" joists, but not 4, or maybe it's only 2?

Yes, I could buy 50 couplings and return the unused ones, however, I have a "plumbing spare parts bin" full of random little things that I've purchased over the years and never got around to actually returning, so I'd like to avoid as much over purchasing as possible, while still having enough on had to get the job done. My bin is only so big...

Comment: To what extent can first floor drains be routed BELOW the bottoms of floor joists? Do these deep notch reinforcement straps have a place?  https://joistrepair.com/products/dp24-deep-notch-repair-kit-2x8-thru-2x12

Comment: Ummm... even at their sale price, they have no place here! Yikes! Unfortunately, I have _very_ little headroom above the drain exit from the house, so I'll need every 1/4" I can find to maintain slope and still have a chance of meeting up with the existing plumbing. Guess I should have clarified that in the question.

Comment: Is the house over a full basement or it it over a crawl space?

Comment: Most of it is a crawl space, the drain exit is in a root cellar. Both have sufficient headroom to work, but neither is particularly deep.

Answer (score 4):

One. Well, *two* once you get it through one and shift it over.

Seriously. The angles are that tough. There's zero effective flex in PVC pipe. You will not get through two joists with the tail end below the third. It's ugly enough that a person is driven to consider cutting a hole in the rim joist and poking pipes in from outside.

I also wonder if anyone ever considers heat-bending temporarily, as with PVC conduit. I'm not sure if that's legal for DWV pipe.

You'll be able to cut it more-or-less the length of the span between joists 1 and 3. You'll have to reduce that length somewhat for the way the pipe encounters the third joist (or the subfloor) at an angle. Practically speaking, plan for a coupling every other joist, plus at least one per run. You can't do a full 32".

Don't forget to allow for slope with your bores. (Thanks for the reminder, Ecnerwal.)

Comment: There's an idea... It does have to go into the old section of the house, I might be able to get some runs straight through from there. TYVM for the great ideas. Keep on throwing them out, I'll catch 'em all!

Comment: Yup. Planning it out so you drill a hole in the rim joist, or some other place where the pipe can slide full-length into the set of joists  is a perfectly reasonable approach if it applies. A hole in the rim joist is easily patched, especially if you get the pipe in before you do the siding for the addition. Remember to allow proper drainage slope.

Comment: 1/4" per foot is well ingrained in my planning. Thanks for double checking! In my case, the long run may be through the rim joist of the old construction, since the new construction rim joist is in the wrong direction, but the idea is solid and I _like_ it a lot!

Comment: Rather than just patching it, the hole in the rim joist seems like a great place to locate a cleanout if it works for the plumbing layout.